# What could cause a message (from a polling receive location) to be ignored by subscribing orchestration?

Tags: biztalk

I'll try provide as much information as possible:

- No error message.
- The instance stays in the "ready service instances".
- The receive location has the same parameters (except URI, the three polling queries, user account/pw and receive pipeline) as another receive location that points to another database/table which works.
- The pipeline is waiting for the correct schema.
- The port surface and receive location are both waiting for the correct schema.
- In my test example, there are only 10 lines being returned.
- The message, which contains those 10 lines, validates against the schema.
- I tried to let the instance alone to no avail - 30+ minutes - and no change in its condition.
- I had also tried suspending and then resuming it which then places the instance in the "dehydrated orchestrations" list. Again, with no error message.
- I'm able to get the message by looking at the body of the message that's in the "ready to run" service. (This is the message that validates versus the schema I use in Visual Studio.)

How might something like this arise?

Comment: have you looked in the event log? Anything there?

Comment: Yes. Again, no error messages but, also, no warnings or anything else.

Comment: What are you subscribing by?  Sometimes I think I have MessageType but when checkin it's Mesage... some other property.

Comment: The publisher, receive loc, is what type?  First thing I'd do is make sure that works by simply pulling and have a send file adapter write data to a file.

Comment: Receive location type: WCF OracleDB - same type as the one that works, by the way.

What do you mean by "subscribing by"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid question, but I have to ask... Is the corresponding host instance running?

Comment: Not at all, I was hoping that someone else would answer it (we figured it out yesterday) before I awarded the answer to myself... It was a new Host but its corresponding Host Instance wasn't even created. Creating it solved the problem.